# How can i set OnClick equal to UnityEvent

Tags: unity, c#

### The Problem

I'm making a dialogue system for a small 2d rpg.
I Have a Dialogue class with two lists for pages and responses. The response class 
has a UnityEvent so i can use the ui in the inspector to set methods like a button.
Then in a DialogueManager class i have a `Show()` method which makes a button for every response in the list from Dialogue. The problem is when i try to set the created button's `OnClick()` event to the UnityEvent in the response.

### The Question

So the question is how can i set the button's `OnClick()` to the methods in the UnityEvent from the response?

Comment: Presumably you read the docs on the button's onClick UnityEvent and tried using [the AddListener method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.AddListener.html) based on the example shown there? Show us what you tried and where specifically you ran into trouble.

Comment: I can't use AddListner because i can't find a way get what methods are in the response's UnityEvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a method that invokes your event:

```
public class DialogueItem : MonoBehaviour {

   public UnityEvent response;

   public void FireResponses() {
       response.Invoke();
   }    

   public void WireUpResponses(Button button) {
       button.onClick.AddListener(FireResponses);
   }
}
```